# Babel minify doesn't load config

Tags: babeljs, babel-preset-minify

```
// contents of widget.js
const { React } = require("react")
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

const App = (props) => {
  return <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
}

const newDiv = document.createElement("div")
newDiv.id = "widget"
document.body.appendChild(newDiv)

ReactDOM.render(App(), document.getElementById('widget'))

// contents of babel.config.json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"
  ]
}
```

running command `minify widget.js --out-file widget.min.js --mangle.keepClassName`
gives this output

> SyntaxError: unknown: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't
> currently enabled (5:10):
>
> Add @babel/preset-react
> (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react)
> to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable
> transformation. If you want to leave it as-is, add
> @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx
> (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx)
> to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

What am I missing to get minify to load presets/plugins?